# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type in wpf

Tags: c#, lambda

```
public void loadtemplist(DataTable dt)
    {
      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,

          (Delegate) (() => this.loadtemplist1(dt))   //error


          );
    }
```

and

```
public void loadtemplist1(DataTable dt)
    {

-----
-----

}
```

the above code throws Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert an anonymous method straight to a `System.Delegate` - you need to wrap it in an `Action` first.

Try this instead:

```
public void loadtemplist(DataTable dt)
{
  this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,

      new Action(() => { this.loadtemplist1(dt); } )
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, 
                            new Action(() => this.loadtemplist1(dt)) );
```

see demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nz9xxD